# Trying to download html table into text file with one column that has a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML table that I am downloading and turning into a text file. However, I have a column that contains a dropdown and only want to get the selected value, not both. The table is dynamically generated. How do I only get the selected value in my text file and not both values in the options? Here is what I have:

```
$('#save-link').click(function ()
{
  var retContent = [];
  var retString = '';

$('thead tr').each(function (idx, elem)
{
   var elemText = [];
$(elem).children('th').each(function (childIdx, childElem)
{
  elemText.push($(childElem).text());
});
  retContent.push(`${elemText.join('   ')}`);
```

});

```
 $('tbody tr').each(function (idx, elem)
 {
    var elemText = [];
$(elem).children('td').each(function (childIdx, childElem)
   {
     elemText.push($(childElem).text());
   });
   retContent.push(`${elemText.join('   ')}`);
 });
retString = retContent.join('\r\n');
var file = new Blob([retString], {type: 'text/plain'});
var btn = $('#save-link');
btn.attr("href", URL.createObjectURL(file));
btn.prop("download", "data.txt");
})
```

The selection column has an ID 'status'. I do not know how to separate from the other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one more line of logic to detect whether the current element you're on is a dropdown or not. For example:

Instead of doing:

```
$(elem).children('td').each(function (childIdx, childElem)
   {
     elemText.push($(childElem).text());
   });
   retContent.push(`${elemText.join('   ')}`);
 });
```

Get the element `tagName` first then figure out how you want to handle it.

```
$(elem).children('td').each(function (childIdx, childElem)
   {
     const el = $(childElem);
     if (el.prop('tagName') === 'SELECT') {
            elementText.push(el.val());
     } else {
            elemText.push($(childElem).text());
     }

   });
   retContent.push(`${elemText.join('   ')}`);
 });
```

Here's a simplified example without jQuery:

```js
const tbody = document.getElementById('tbod');
const dataArray = [];
const trs = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr');
for (let i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
 const tr = trs[i];
  const tds = tr.querySelectorAll('td');
  for (let j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
   const element = tds[j];
    const select = element.querySelector('select');
    if (select) {
     dataArray.push(select.value);
    } else {
     dataArray.push(element.innerText);
    }
  }
}
console.log(dataArray);
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Just Text</th>
      <th>Dropdowns</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbod">
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="1" selected>One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! My select is generated by data though. Like this:

tbl +='<td ><select id="status" name="status" class="status" data-id="'+row_id+'">';
      tbl += '<option' + (val['IncludeThis'] == "yes" ? ' selected' : '') + '>yes</option>';
      tbl += '<option' + (val['IncludeThis'] == "no" ? ' selected' : '') + '>no</option>';
      tbl += '</select></td>';

How can I use the tagname here? I tried 

 if (el.prop('tagName') === 'status') {
            elementText.push(el.val());

With no success

Comment: It's all the same. Generated by code or static. It's all the same.